# Ajax и post запрос на одной странице не срабатывают

Tags: ajax, javascript

Приветствую всех вошедших )

```
<!--AJAX-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    function updates(){
        $.ajax({
            //посылаем запрос определенной странице (push.php), возвращаем через seccess..
        })
    }
    setTimeout(updates, 1000);//каждую секунду выполняем ф-ю updates!

});
</script>

<!--POST-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.post('page.php', { fields_one: fields_one }, function(data){
        //перевариваем переменные
    }, 'json');

});
</script>
```

Вопрос поправил, в силу некоторой неточности..

Вообщем скрипт номер 2 работает 3 минуты - и ответ от него получается очень медленный, а вот верхний скрипт по идее должен работать каждую секунду. Если использовать скрипты по отдельности - сбоев нет. Если вместе -> первый дает задержку как второй. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: а на сервере что происходит?

Comment: Возможно второй запрос делает что-то косячное(ресурсоемкое) на сервере, и блокирует остальные запросы.